# Converting *.ram to *.avi

Tags: conversion, ram, avi

I just came across an old file witn a ram extension. I've tried viewing it ( just to see what it is ) and am having extreme difficulties. I've tried looking for spftware online and alll I find are Windows programs and some online conversion sites.I would like to have a local utility convert such files.

Does anyone know something?

How about for other weird file formats?

Comment: The extention sounds like [Real Audio Metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealAudio). Does `less $filename` show anything recognizable? What is the output of `file $filename`? Is `mplayer` able to play it?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the conversions can be handled by `ffmpeg` which comes with a amazing number of codecs.

To convert your file, try the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.rma file.avi
```

Useful information about a file can be retrieved using the `file` command. Remember that `avi` or `rma` are just containers, so two `avi` files may not use the same encoding for audio or video. That's why a conversion from `ram` to `avi` may not work in all cases, if one of the codec used in the original file is not supported by `ffmpeg`.

For example, on my computer, with three different files:

```
> file file1.avi 
file1.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 720 x 400, 25.00 fps, video: DivX 4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
> file file2.avi 
file2.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 608 x 336, ~24 fps, video: Motion JPEG
> file file3.avi 
file3.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 304, 25.00 fps, video: DivX 4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 24000 Hz)
```

Comment: While ffmpeg is great for encoding, I'd prefer mplayer for a file in wtf-format.